# Print my table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me with this? I just want to print this table using javascript print mode. But how? Using also the print view in the web style. I really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance. :)
[image]

Here's my code.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dailytimerecord WHERE CONCAT(Dtrec_ID, TimeIn, TimeOut) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
  } else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dailytimerecord";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
  }
  function filterTable($query) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alqdb");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
    <style>
      table,tr,th,td {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
  <input type="button" name="print" value="Print"><br><br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Dtrec_ID</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time In</th>
      <th>Time Out</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Dtrec_ID'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['TimeIn']));?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("h:i, A", strtotime($row['TimeIn']))?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("h:i, A", strtotime($row['TimeOut']));?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean you want your "print" button to pop up the browser's print dialog? Or are you talking about styling the table specifically for print media using CSS? `window.print();` will show the print dialog.